# Odoo 16 - Website editor - I cannot edit on my website

Tags: web, mixed-content, odoo-16

I use Apache as reverse proxy, I'd installed Website on Odoo 16 and when I try to go to Editor it doesn't resolve the page.

At developer tools of my browser appears this error:

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://rcr.ar/web#action=178&cids=1&menu_id=116' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://rcr.ar/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Let me know if you need more information.

Best regards and thanks,

Emilio

I try to open Editor at Odoo Website
I expect to edit my website.
The page doesn't appears and result an error of Mixed Content

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```xml
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

to httpd.conf under IfModule headers_module to look like follows

```xml
<IfModule headers_module>
    #
    # Avoid passing HTTP_PROXY environment to CGI's on this or any proxied
    # backend servers which have lingering "httpoxy" defects.
    # 'Proxy' request header is undefined by the IETF, not listed by IANA
    #
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>
```

I have also created a bug with [bncert-tool](https://github.com/bitnami/vms/issues/778) for the same